# Meteor / Blaze confusion over naming conventions

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Just running through the Meteor tutorial. I'm currently at the update / remove section https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/update-and-remove

The code shows

```
<template name="task">
<li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
<button class="delete">&times;</button>

<input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

<span class="text">{{text}}</span>
</li>
</template>
```

I'm about confused about where 'checked' needs to be the same. Is it only in the curly braces?

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces invoke the data binding to the template data or helpers

the `{{checked}}` in curly braces will be substituted with the current data value (int this case the `true` or `false` depending on the state of the item in your database).

As `checked` is a boolean value, this will render as true or false depending on what is stored in your item.